# QSSTV on Linux Mint

Tags: software, linux, sstv

Linux Mint MATE 64 (system is up to date)

I installed qsstv 
first it runs normally but no CAT ..
then I installed hamlib and put in the same string for the USB Device like in FlDigi which runs now UFB!  (`/dev/serial/by-id/usb-Silicon_Labs_CP2105_Dual_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_00733873-if00-port0`) 
Also chose the FT-991 for my FT-991A

1. Now if I start qsstv (without error) it is very slow (needs 12% from systemtime)..nearly not possible to do something else with my PC.
   ? I have no idea why...
2. For the device `/dev/serial/by-id/usb-Silicon_Labs_CP2105_Dual_USB_to_UART_Bridge_Controller_00733873-if00-port0`, I made a sym link eg 991a - but after I restart Mint the sym Link is gone. Why ?

Comment: Have you searched for *qsstv* on the LM forums?

Comment: What version of QSSTV are you using?

Comment: TNX I will look into LM Forum, and the Version is 9.2.6
Also will go and get the latest one and build them from source.

Has really something to do with the hamlib - only if I mark "use hamlib" then are the issues. Decoding (without hamlib) have good results, also Editor  etc all ok.

Comment: OK TNX for suggestion.
Now it works - but without CAT control.
The PTT is doing by VOX -
The pictures are (if reception is acceptale) in good quality.
Also sending is no problem.
With this (manually tuning the frequency I am able to live) 
SSTV is not a stressy mode 
TNX to all Erich

Comment: For me is it now running, no Cat but with VOX. Had good results.
TNX

Answer (score 1):

I once successfully used QSSTV on Linux Mint for displaying digital pictures. However, at some point after upgrading LM it ceased working correctly. It would just not lock onto a signal anymore. But I did not have [the latest version](http://users.telenet.be/on4qz/qsstv/index.html).

If you want to try getting it working, I suggest that you forget the symlink until after you get the software working right.

Try increasing qsstv's priority to something a little less than 100%, say 80%. An easy way to do that is from within htop (`sudo apt-install htop`).

I suggest that you search on on the Debian-based Linux forums for QSSTV. If you find a solution, then by all means post it as an answer here! :-)

If you install an earlier version of LM in a virtual machine as a guest OS, QSSTV might very well work.  Virtualbox and Mint MATE 18.1 should do it. Just don't upgrade LM 18.1, or you risk having the same problem that you do now. Don't install Virtualbox using Synaptic, etc. Instead, download everything from [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/virtualization/technologies/vm/downloads/virtualbox-downloads.html). And afterwards, be sure you install the guest extensions.

Comment: Perhaps the Windows version of SSTV will run in WINE. First, check winehq.org .

Comment: Are you sure you're not thinking of a different app? QSSTV source code has always been available (I always build it from source), the most recent release was just a couple months ago, and to the best of my knowledge ON4QZ is alive and well.

Comment: @hobbs-KC2G Evidently, ON4QZ has taken over the project from either PA3ABA or PA3MBO. I have version 8.2.12 on this LM box. What is the latest version, and where is the QSSTV website?

Comment: 9.4.4 at http://users.telenet.be/on4qz/qsstv/index.html